# Nuxt.js/Axios self signed certificate error

Tags: vue.js, axios, ssl-certificate, nuxt.js, self-signed

I have a problem with making a local `GET` request from http to https.

Situation:
I use a tool called Local(https://localwp.com/) to quickly generate a local WordPress development environment. It's local address is https://backend.local (via host file). I also have a Nuxt.js app running on http://localhost:3000.

With axios, I try to make a `GET` request to the WordPress REST api, but I get the following error:

```
NuxtServerError

self signed certificate
```

If I try the `fetch` method, I get the following response:

```
FetchError
request to https://backend.local/wp-json/wp/v2/posts failed, reason: self signed certificate
```

It only works, when I make a `GET` request to a non-local URL.

But after a few hours of googling and trying all the solutions, nothing worked and I am getting a bit frustrated now :)

My setup is: MacBook Pro 2019 Catalina 10.15.4, Chrome 83.0.4103.61

I hope someone has an answer for me :)

Thank you!

Comment: First hit when searching for _"nuxt accept self-signed certificate"_ ~ https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6559

Comment: Thank you @phil, but I tried that and didnt work :)

Comment: @phil I am very sorry, your answer did work. It just threw a differrent unrelated error, I managed to solve it now. Thank you!

Comment: I wasn't sure that would work but that's why it was a comment and not an answer. Feel free to add your solution below though, I'm sure it will help others in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I followed those steps](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6559#issuecomment-541926588) and got to fix the issue:

#### 1. Create a `plugins` folder, if it doesn't exist. Inside `plugins` folder, create `axios.js` file with the following:

```js
import https from 'https';

export default function ({ $axios }) {
    $axios.defaults.httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false });
}
```

#### 2. At `nuxt.config.js` file, find the `plugins` section, and add the following:

```js
// Other configurations here
plugins: [
    // Other plugins here
    '@/plugins/axios',
],
// Rest of the file
```

Comment: I've got this problem with a project that is trying to build dynamic routes for a static app. 5 weeks ago it ran fine. I run it now and I'm getting this error. I don't know of any intentional changes that have caused this so I'm at a loss right now. I've tried the above, and tried setting SSL to false on my /api/ path but nothing works. I should also mention that I'm trying to call my local API inside nuxt.config.js. I just thought of a change, upgraded my .NET API from 5.0 to 6.0... hmmm.

Comment: The solution doesn't work for me, for today